# Prove that there exist complete metric spaces of any cardinal number

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I refer to this proof
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/823148/748810

Can I modify it to make the proof work?

Comment: Can't you just take any set of a given cardinality and use the discrete metric on it?

Answer (score 0):

For any set $X$ take $d: X \times X \to \Bbb R$ the discrete metric

$$d(x,y)=\begin{cases} 0&x=y\\1 & x \neq y\end{cases}$$

and note that $(X,d)$ is complete: any $d$-Cauchy sequence $(x_n)_n$ is eventually constant, and hence convergent.

If you're looking for spaces without isolated points, you cannot really say much for sure about size $\aleph_1$ (if that happens to be $< \mathfrak{c}$), that depends on how CH fails exactly).. And if $X$ is at least continuum, $\Bbb R \times (X,d)$ is complete and without isolated points and of size $|X|$, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess you are using open sets? I was thinking of using a closed subset F of a complete metric space with its limit points. Start with 1 set with so many points count them. Stick another one inside with less and count them , invoke Theorem 9 partial ordering on cardinals...

Comment: @Shaggy You're making no sense to me.. I'm not talking about open or closed sets, but about the fact that a discrete metric space is complete.

Comment: I was looking for spaces that are complete without isolated points I thought isolated points occur in open sets

Comment: @Shaggy discrete metric spaces have no limit points.

Comment: Correct. I wanted to work with limit points. But I think what you are saying we can’t be sure and it would fail AC.
In my last comment I meant “with” not “without “

Comment: @Shaggy A complete metric space of size $\aleph_1$ so that all its points are limit points cannot exist if we are in a model of ZFC + MA + not CH. So it follows you cannot construct one without assuming extra axioms beyond ZFC.

Comment: That’s what I was afraid of

Comment: I think this has to do with the fact that R is uncountable else my knowledge of metric spaces has holes in it